# How to determine one value when given average of some of the items, and a percentage?

Tags: statistics, average, word-problem

The question states the following:

> Helen's score on a final test in a certain course was 60 percent
>   greater than her average (arithmetic mean) score of the 2 other tests
>   taken in the course. Helen's score on the final test was what percent
>   of the student's average test score for the entire course?

I solved this by setting up the following equations:

$f$ = score on the final test
$a+b$ = sum of scores on the first two tests

So, given the information in the problem, I set up the following equations:

$$f=1.6*\frac{a+b}{2}$$
$$f=x*\frac{a+b+f}{3}$$

where $x$ is obviously the answer that we're seeking:  the percentage (as a decimal) of the average for the entire course.

Solve for $a+b$ and get $a+b=\frac{f}{0.8}$.  Plugging that into the second equation I get the following:

$$f=\frac{\frac{f}{0.8}+f}{3}x$$

And solving for $x$ I'm getting $x=6/7$.

But this is not the correct answer.

Can someone please point out where my logic is incorrect?

Thanks.

Comment: By solving $f=\frac{\frac{f}{0.8}+f}{3}x$ we find $x=4/3$, i.e. $33.33$ percent greater than the average test score for the entire course.

Comment: Oh, thank you @RobertZ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a third score $60\%$ greater than the average of the first two scores will increase the average by $\frac{60\%}{3} = 20\%$

IOW, new average $= \frac{100 + 100 +160}{3}$ which is $120\%$ of the old average.

$\frac{160}{120} = \frac{4}{3}$ which is $133.333\%$

Comment: Thanks Phil.  I see what I missed.